# Finding max value in a min- heap

Tags: data-structures, big-o-notation

What is the time complexity of finding the maximal value in a minimum heap with n nodes?
Can I assume the maximal value is in one of leafs? If yes, there are ceil n/2 leafs. Does that make the time complexity to O(ceil[n/2]).
Is there a way to find the maximal value in O(logn)?

Comment: Note that $\lceil n/2 \rceil =O(n)$. And yes, the max must be in one of the leaves. Are you required to only use min heap? Or you can use something like a [min-max heap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap)

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value *must* be a leaf, otherwise the heap condition would be violated at that node. For an $O(\log n)$ complexity to be possible, the leaves should be in sorted order, and that does not make a standard heap anymore (updates would be quite different).